# Suggestion - Optimize production bundle

Tags: here-api

Greetings to all this may concern,

I've been using Here JS SDK for a year, and recently I'm gathering efforts to get my app most performatic and lighweight. My project started with create-react-app v4 (webpack 4), and in order to upgrade to better options, I've migrated to vite and its been working fine. To lookup for bundle sizes, I have a tool showing every dep size, so i can improve loading times.

[here bundle size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5f7v.png)

The JS SDK represents almost 30% percent of the assets, I think this can be optimized to reduce the bundle in client side. The adoption of ESM may be a good choice to get better results.

Comment: Dear User, Could you please share which SDK like explore, navigate etc you are using?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I'm using Maps API for JS https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.35.1/dev_guide/index.html combining map tiles with routing

Answer (score 0):

By default, the MapView is rendered with 60 frames per second (FPS). Via `mapView.get/setFrameRate()`
the maximum frame rate can be adjusted

Please use below link for Performance Optimization:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.12.8.0/dev_guide/topics/maps.html#performance-optimization